# Parallel Query OrderBy and ForAll placement

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

Is it illogical to use a forall statement after an orderby statement, such as:
`array.AsParallel().Orderby(n => n.ToString()).ForAll(n => {});` in a parallel query as the order will be scrapped by the forall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OrderBy` operation introduces "order preservation" into all subsequent operations in a query. That means the order will be preserved even though it's parallel.

However, `ForAll` will "Execute nondeterministically in parallel", so ordering the sequence first and then *only* using a `ForAll` that does not care does indeed not make much sense.

Read more on Order Preservation in PLINQ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The relevant part from the link is that `ForAll()` "Executes nondeterministically in parallel", even if the source sequence is ordered. Which means the `OrderBy()` indeed doesn't make sense in the above query.